# Can't add an item as first item in array - php array_unshift()

Tags: php, arrays, codeigniter

Hi I'd like some help please.

```
// categories for dropdown
$this->data['dropdown_items'] = $this->category_model->get_key_value('id', 'category_name');
```

This line of my code returns an array as a key=>value pair array. So if I dump $this->data['dropdown_items'] on screen I get this:

```
array(8) {
  [1] => "cinemas"
  [5] => "theaters"
  [7] => "night life"
  [6] => "restaurants"
  [4] => "food"
  [2] => "night clubs"
  [3] => "opera"
  [8] => "misc"
}
i.e [id] => "the category name"
```

What I'd like to do is to prepend/add as first item of this array a new item
so I tried to add it with array_unshift() function:

```
$this->data['dropdown_items'] = array_unshift($this->data['dropdown_items'], "Please select a category");
```

This is what I was hopping to get:

```
array(8) {
      [0] => "Please select a category"
      [1] => "cinemas"
      [5] => "theaters"
      [7] => "night life"
      [6] => "restaurants"
      [4] => "food"
      [2] => "night clubs"
      [3] => "opera"
      [8] => "misc"
    }
```

but instead when I dump the $this->data['dropdown_items'] , I get the following

```
int(9)
```

Any ideas what's wrong?

Comment: `array_unshift` modifies the array in place, no need to assign what it returns.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

replace this

```
$this->data['dropdown_items'] = array_unshift($this->data['dropdown_items'], "Please select a category");
```

with

```
array_unshift($this->data['dropdown_items'], "Please select a category");
```

[array_unshit](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-unshift.php) returns number of elements in array  that`s why you are getting array count

Comment: its ok its happen with all :)

Answer (score 1):

array_unshift receive a reference array in first argument :

```
array_unshift($this->data['dropdown_items'], "Please select a category");
```

If you assign the return value to your array, it will be replace by the number of elements in your array (int).